# Does the dual BLE module RN-4677 from Microchip use the MLDP profile

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip

Does the dual BLE module RN-4677 from Microchip use the MLDP profile? I have searched in all datasheets but I couldn't find the answer. The datasheet says only:

> In addition to SPP for Bluetooth Classic connectivity, the RN4677 introduces a private Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) service for serial data transfer between two BLE devices. This BLE data streaming service provided in the RN4677 is named “Transparent UART”. Therefore, the RN4677 is a Dual mode Bluetooth module, which supports both Bluetooth Classic and BLE serial data connectivity.

But in some other datasheets of Microchip e.g. for the RN4020 it say's

> For all supported profiles and services, the RN4020 module can be configured to act as server and client roles at the same time. Furthermore, the RN4020 module supports the private Microchip Low-energy Data Profile (MLDP), which provides an asynchronous serial data connection between two RN4020 devices.

So is that the same or are there differences? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the MLDP is implemented in the RN-4677.

Answer (score 1):

No MLDP is not implemented in the RN4677 !
The only implemented service is a "Transparent UART" wich is different.
Besides this, you still can create yourself a similar UART between RN4020 & RN4677 by using the services that are used by RN4677 for the Transparent UART implementation.
To do so, first you need to understand how services and characteristics works in the Blutooth Low Energy standart. In this case Microchip defined a private service and characteristics with special UUIDs in the RN4677. This is what you'll work with.
Here is a demo code on RN4020 which illustrates how the link works

http://txt.do/5iqhe

Hope this helps.